# How do I ignore order of identical elements with XMLUnit's DetailedDifference?

Tags: java, xmlunit

I want to compare two xml files using XMLUnit. I would like the DetailedDiff to not report identical tags in different orders as differences. For example, if I created a DetailedDiff with these two snippets:

```
 <a><b/><c/></a>
```

and

```
<a><c/><b/></a>
```

The DetailedDiff will create two Differences since the b and c tags are out of order. I have tried overriding element qualifiers but it doesn't result in any changes. Am I doing something wrong or is this impossible to do with XMLUnit? For reference here's the code I'm using to compare two xml files (not including overrideElementQualifier calls).

```
public List<Difference> getDifferenceList(Reader file1, Reader file2) {
    Diff d = new Diff(file1, file2); //I'm passing the args as FileReaders
    d.overrideElementQualifier(new RecursiveElementNameAndTextQualifier());
    detailedDiff = new DetailedDiff(d);
    List<Difference> allDifferences = detailedDiff.getAllDifferences();
    return allDifferences;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`RecursiveElementNameAndTextQualifier` will yield the same result as the default `ElementNameQualifier` - b and c are out of order but other than that the documents are identical.

Elements that are out of order constitute a recoverable difference, so `Diff` and `DetailedDiff` will say the documents are "similar" but not "identical".  So either you ignore recoverable differences or you must override the `DifferenceListener` rather than the `ElementQualifier` to downgrade a difference of type `CHILD_NODELIST_SEQUENCE_ID` from `RETURN_IGNORE_DIFFERENCE_NODES_SIMILAR` (the default) to `RETURN_IGNORE_DIFFERENCE_NODES_IDENTICAL`.  Something like

```
public int differenceFound(Difference difference) {
    return difference.getId() == DifferenceConstants.CHILD_NODELIST_SEQUENCE_ID
        ? RETURN_IGNORE_DIFFERENCE_NODES_IDENTICAL
        : RETURN_ACCEPT_DIFFERENCE;
}
```

which accepts the default but downgrades just the out-of-order differences.

Comment: This is perfect answer. Thank you.. However I need to ignore the nodes which are not existent. Since I do not want to see in the result output such a output: Expected presence of child node "null" but was ......How can I do that? Regards.

Comment: For this you can use the same approach @limonik - the difference you want to ignore is `CHILD_NODE_NOT_FOUND_ID` and probably `CHILD_NODELIST_LENGTH_ID`.